# method based linq is always better than query based linq or it has some restriction?

Tags: linq

I have seen people giving preference to method based linq ( in c#), so i wanted to know
where one should use a method based on linq and where one should use query-based linq?

yours sincerely

Comment: The main different is readability. For `groupby`, `thenby` and `let`, I think query syntax is easier to read, but for `Where` and `Select` it doesn't make much difference. Also, since you can't extend query syntax, if you want to use your own operators (such as outer join) you will be using lambda syntax. And, of course, unfortunately operators like `Distinct` only have a lambda version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion it's down to the more compact size of the syntax, if you write the full SQL like query based stuff all the time then you classes will become swamped and you are likely to miss what was the intended logic of the method or class.

Both are semantically identical, see: [Query Syntax and Method Syntax in LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/query-syntax-and-method-syntax-in-linq)

> At compile time, query expressions are converted to Standard Query Operator method calls according to the rules set forth in the C# specification. Any query that can be expressed by using query syntax can also be expressed by using method syntax. However, in most cases query syntax is more readable and concise. For more information, see C# Language Specification and Standard Query Operators Overview.

So ultimately it's down to which you prefer to use but I would always encourage another developer to try and learn method based syntax due to it's compact size and it's also the most commonly used in my experience.